# Add value of icon into input field on icon click

Tags: javascript, icons, font-awesome

HTML PART

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary p-1 m-1"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square fa-2x mt-1" value="fab fa-instagram-square" onclick="changeValue(this)"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary p-1 m-1"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x mt-1" value="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary p-1 m-1"><i class="fab fa-tiktok fa-2x mt-1" value="fab fa-tiktok"></i></a>
    
<input class="form-control w-100" id="icon" name="icon">
```

This is what I tested and not wrking well

```
function changeValue(o){
  document.getElementById('icon').value=o.innerHTML;
 }
```

My wish is to add/change value of the input with icon value or even better the class (example: fab fa-instagram-square).

My result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get class of the icon clicked , you can use className

```
document.getElementById('icon').value=o.className;
```

Comment: Hope you are not missing any information that you have shared in above code. As according to the code, using className will give the class of the icon i.e "fab fa-instagram-square fa-2x mt-1"

Comment: based on image shared seems like you are working with svg. Can you please the html you are working with?

Comment: I'm using fontawesome CDN JS library, that's why there is SVG.

Comment: Here is the html

Comment: try this : o.className.baseVal;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227643/discussion-between-kkoss-asa-and-meenakshi).